# Is there a name for such political abbreviations as "libfem" for liberal feminism and "ancap" for anarcho-capitalism?

Tags: terminology, abbreviations, politics

In the last ten years or so, I've seen these strange abbreviations all over the Internet. Besides the ones in the above title, I've seen these examples: "tradcath", "nazbol", "neolib", and "socdem". I remember "neocon" becoming popular during the George W. Bush presidency, but overall, the abbreviations remind me of the Soviet abbreviations (e.g., "Comintern", "agitprop", "politburo", "Gosplan", "combed") that Orwell parodied in 1984 (e.g., "Ingsoc", "Minitrue").

But I can't find any discussion of them that might explain where they come from, or even (what I'm asking for now) a term that refers to them. Does anyone know what they're called? Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the question, it's on-topic but some users are more cautious and wary than others. Saying that, "nazbol" is a decidedly unpleasant reminder of people's worst demons...

Comment: @Mari-LouA I fear I must question the question’s premise about this being anything new under the sun; it smacks of the [recency illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recency_illusion). After all, “telescoped names” (that is, syllabic acronyms; see [paywalled OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/1844?rskey=stc1BO)) have been around forever, antedating even the *libdems* by a country mile, whether that’s *Nikon* (< *Nippon Kōgaku Kōgyō Kabushikigaisha*), *Interpol, Benelux, Nabisco,* or *Desron*.

Comment: Don't forget _wingnut_, from _right-wing nut-case_. The metaphors are stacked there like Russian matryoshke.

Comment: If this question focuses on single or a specific kind of abbreviation, and loses its incidental political context, it could be a good addition to our site, as we don't *seem* (based on a quick search) to have a similar question.

Comment: There are official ones and ones made up by anybody at all. Not the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're known as **syllabic abbreviations** according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviation#Syllabic_abbreviation). The origin of that should be obvious: they're abbreviations made up of syllables.

They are more common in German, where a syllabic abbreviation is known as a *[Silbenwort](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silbenwort)* (syllable word), or *Silbenkurzwort* (syllable abbreviation), so you might want to use one of those term if discussing German examples like *Gestapo* (Geheime Staatspolizei) and *Stazi* (Staatssicherheit). Other languages also use them more than English: they're also associated with the Soviet Union, e.g. *Comintern*, *Comsomol*.

Comment: One learning for me from the Wikipedia you linked: "Syllabic abbreviations should be distinguished from portmanteaus, which combine two words without necessarily taking whole syllables from each." So I guess these are a subclass of portmanteaus

Comment: There's a difference between official ones and unofficial ones. Comintern is official while tradcath is not. They are not at all the same thing.